# Why is crystal reports 2016 not showing all the tables and views in the database expert?

Tags: crystal-reports

I just install crystal report 2016 32bit.  My ERP tables and views are not visible from the Database expert for the odbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rklesolutions.com/blog/crystal-reports-objects-database

I modified the NTablesMax REG_DWORD from 8000 objects to 0 for unlimited load. Crystal hits the 8000 object limit and fails to load the views and tables for vista. Setting NTablesMax to 0 in the registry tell crystal to load all tables and views.